# CoreBlutooth setNotifyValue error: "The request is not supported."

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

i try to write app with connect to bluetooth and send some data and get response, but got error when try to set: setNotifyValue 
I start search with

```
self.centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [serviceUUID], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true])
```

after i connect to peripheral

```
public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

    self.discoveredPeripheral = peripheral
    self.discoveredPeripheral!.delegate = self
    self.centralManager?.stopScan()
    self.centralManager?.connect(self.discoveredPeripheral!, options: nil)

}
```

after connect i discover services

```
public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    self.discoveredPeripheral!.discoverServices([serviceUUID])
}
```

after discover charachteristic

```
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    if let services = peripheral.services{
        for service in services {
            if service.uuid.isEqual(serviceUUID) {
                self.discoveredPeripheral!.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)

            }
        }
    } else{
        print("errors")
    }
}
```

after i save characteristic and try setNotifyValue to true

```
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
    if let charachteristics = service.characteristics {
        for charactiristic in charachteristics {
            if charactiristic.uuid.isEqual(readCharacteristicUUID) {
                self.readCharacteristic = charactiristic
            } else if charactiristic.uuid.isEqual(writeCharacteristicUUID) {
                self.writeCharacteristic = charactiristic
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: charactiristic)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

but in i got error:

```
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    print("didUpdateNotification")
    if error != nil {
        print((error!.localizedDescription))

    }
}
```

> The request is not supported.

in android it possible to connect with response

does anyone ideas, what is wrong and how fix this ?

I try restart phone: [CBCentralManager setNotifyValue: not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360347/cbcentralmanager-setnotifyvalue-not-working)
but it doesn't help

Comment: Could you check the value `properties` of `self.writeCharacteristic`: `self.writeCharacteristic.properties`.

Comment: @Larme Hi i checked and it's very strange, in write characteristic i have only true on charactiristic.properties.contains(.write)(and not notify) and in read characteristic i have only true in charactiristic.properties.contains(.notify)(and not read) how can i write with response in this way ?

Comment: Your BLE device is not correctly set. I think that iOS check before hand the properties.

Comment: Why would you be able to set notify on a write characteristic?  You write to write characteristics whenever you want. You use notify on read characteristics so that the peripheral can notify you that there is data to be read.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, i was notify read and get delegate didUpdateNotificationStateFor, after i write data to write characteristic and get delegate didWriteValueFor, but i have not call in didUpdateValueFor characteristic, what i do wrong ?

Comment: Your peripheral needs to write a value to the characteristic and indicate before you will get a call to the `didUpdateValueFor` method.  Writing a value to a characteristic won't trigger `didUpdateValueFor`